# Flutter Scroll only with buttons

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, frontend

I want to create this login form with Flutter: [image: ScrollPic]

and I think the easiest way would be to have a

```
Form( ...
    ListView( ....
    [Login Card] 
    [Social Card]
    [Register Card]));
```

but for that it should only be possible to scroll thought this listview with this two(or 4) buttons not with the fingers, and the buttons automatically navigate to the very bottom or very top. Is there a way to do this with a ListView with a ScrollController e.g. ?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can also check `index_to_scroll`packge or perhaps you like to have  Stepper widget.

Comment: That'd just be a PageView, I think.

Comment: Oh thank you, a PageView looks goot. But any idea how do I prevent the user from Scrolling with fingers? Only with Buttons is there an option or that?